# `node distance=#1` appears to be ineffective under TikZ 3.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I was not having this problem before I upgraded (note `node distance=5in`):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
  node distance=3cm,
  graph vertex/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=7.5mm,
  },
  graph directed edge/.style={
    >=stealth,
    ->,
    semithick,
  },
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5in]
    \foreach \posx/\posy/\name in {
      1/3/A,
      0/3/B,
      2/3/C,
      3/3/D,
      1/2/E,
      3/2/F,
      0/1/G,
      2/1/H,
      1/0/I,
      3/1/J}
    \node[graph vertex] (\name) at ((\posx,\posy) {\name};
  \foreach \source/\sink in {A/C,A/H,B/A,B/G,C/D,D/F,E/A,E/I,F/J,G/I,H/F,H/G,I/H,J/C}
    \path[graph directed edge] (\source) edge (\sink);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You give explicit coordinates so it doesn't have any need to use `node distance` no?

Comment: As I can see, you overwrite node distance with absolute node coordinates in \foreach loop ...

Comment: Try setting `x=...in` and `y=...in`.

Comment: @percusse perhaps I am misunderstanding the point of the key. I thought it was this key that controlled the scale of the coordinate system, no?

Comment: @Henri I'm afraid I don't follow… my TikZ skills are somewhat fledgling :)

Comment: Also, it seems like the `scale=` key does (almost) exactly what I want to do (less the ability to explicitly declare the sale of the coordinate system), but it can't be included in a `\tikzset`.  Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: node distnce controls the distance when you place things relatively. such as left something or abive some node etc.

Comment: @percusse Didn't know that at the time. Perhaps someone can make that an answer and I can look around separately for an answer to my comment just above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node distance controls the automatic distance when things are placed relative to each other. Simple example;

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt}]
    \node[] (A) {A};
    \node[left=of A] (B) {B};

    \begin{scope}[node distance=2cm]
    \node[right=of A] (C) {C};        
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[node distance=1mm]
    \node[above=of A] (D) {D};        
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding your `scale` issue, it is a picture or node key hence it has to be read in the right context. Having only,

```
\tikzset{scale=3}
```

doesn't invoke anything since every tikzpicture environment needs to read it during initialization. If I understand your comment correctly you can put such specs in the `every picture` key. Using the handle `/.prefix style` makes it possible to override it in individual cases, for example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.prefix style={scale=3}} % For every tikz picture

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[] %scale=3
    \draw  (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]% Overrides the key on this one since those keys are prefixed
    %Now the scale is 1.5!!! Transformations are cumulative
    \draw  (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[reset cm,scale=0.5]% Overrides the key on this one since those keys are prefixed
    %Now the scale is 0.5!!! We reset the transformation
    \draw  (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Applying to your example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{%node distance=3cm,
  graph vertex/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=7.5mm,
  },
  graph directed edge/.style={
    >=stealth,
    ->,
    semithick,
  },
  every picture/.prefix style={scale=3}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \foreach \posx/\posy/\name in {
      1/3/A,
      0/3/B,
      2/3/C,
      3/3/D,
      1/2/E,
      3/2/F,
      0/1/G,
      2/1/H,
      1/0/I,
      3/1/J}
    \node[graph vertex] (\name) at ((\posx,\posy) {\name};
  \foreach \source/\sink in {A/C,A/H,B/A,B/G,C/D,D/F,E/A,E/I,F/J,G/I,H/F,H/G,I/H,J/C}
    \path[graph directed edge] (\source) edge (\sink);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also wish to have the transformation to be applied to nodes you need to put `transform shape` key in the style or explicitly in the node options.